# C++ operator overloading for embedded DSL language in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Is it possible to use C++ operator overloading and create a DSL-like syntax for embedded DsL code in c++.

```
"a": auto = call("add2Numbers", "b", "c");
```

This is what I would like ideally. But anything close to this as valid C++ would be acceptable.

Comment: And what should that do actually? I doubt you can do any trickery to make this valid c++ syntax. (I well know what DSL's are BTW)

Comment: Enclosing it with `#if 0` `#endif` technically makes it valid C++, but you probably want something to happen. What?

Comment: As long as I am able to store all the information present here in some C++ object I am good. I can then process this somehow.

Comment: You can look at Boost:Spirit for an idea of operator overloading to accomplish what you desire.

Comment: One form that i had was call("a", "auto", "add2numbers", "b", c"). this is fine but is less readable. I am trying to improve readability

Comment: Is `auto a = call("add2Numbers", "b", "c");` close enough?

Answer (score 2):

Good advice: don't. `C++` is a big multi purpose language and already complicated enough. You *will* confuse people (and yourself too!) if you randomly change stuff. Especially operator overloading and the proposed pre processor should be treated carefully.

My advice for you is to write the functions you need. You gave an example about some kind of assignment (sorry, don't understand the given code) and I'm sure it is perfectly possible to write a function with a convenient interface to achieve what you're trying to do. The advantage is that your synthax stays all `C++` and possible readers (and again your future self) don't get confused.

I hope I understood your question properly. If not, please correct me.

Felix

Comment: Since I don't know how good you are with `C++` programming, it should be noted that you can pass your variables by reference to a function. Passing by reference means, that you still work with the original passed variable in the function and changes to it apply to the variable of the caller function (e.g. `main()`) aswell.

I don't know if this helps you anyhow; I just wanted to state that this exists.